# Android - ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter + PageTransformer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, android-pagetransformer

In my app I use a ViewPager in conjunction with PageTransformer to display some data list as a card deck. That list is sometimes refreshed and it contains plenty of items in a common case, so I use FragmentStatePagerAdapter with needed page limit:

```
public class PlaceListPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private List<PlaceListData> items;

    public PlaceListPagerAdapter (FragmentManager manager) {
        super (manager);

        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        String id = items.get(position).getId();
        String name = items.get(position).getName();
        String address = items.get(position).getAddress();

        return PlaceFragment.newInstance(id, name, address);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        PlaceFragment frag = (PlaceFragment) object;
        String id = frag.getDataId();

        for (PlaceListData data : items) {
            if (id != null && id.equals(data.getId())) {
                return POSITION_UNCHANGED;
            }
        }

        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void addItems(List<PlaceListData> items) {
        this.items.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void replaceItems(List<PlaceListData> items) {
        this.items.clear();
        addItems(items);
    }

    public void clearItems () {
        this.items.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Nothing unusual - list of pojos, overriden getItemPosition() and add/clear methods with notifyDataSetChanged(). The problem is when I try to add/replace items over network, method **transformPage(View view, float position)** of my transformer is called with 0.0 position for all new views and they are placed one over another (transformation is broken).

After debugging ViewPager class I noticed that **transformPage(View view, float position)** is invoked only in one place in **onPageScrolled(..)** method of ViewPager and the latter is invoked in **onLayout(..)** after the first layout pass.

notifyDataSetChanged() invokes **onPageScrolled(..)** (and **transformPage(View view, float position)** respectively) and **requestLayout()** after that. The problem is that first invocation of **transformPage(View view, float position)** happens before layout pass and **position** parameter depends on **View.left()** which returns 0 as child views are not layouted. In **onLayout(..)** which follows the **requestLayout()** my **transformPage(View view, float position)** is not called at all because yeap, views are layouted now, but it is not the first layout pass.

The problem is cured by resetting adapter (it sets **mFirstLayout** flag in ViewPager to "true") or by calling any public method of ViewPager which invokes **transformPage(View view, float position)** in it's code such as **scrollTo**, **fakeDrag** etc, but I'd like to know - is all that a feature of ViewPager or is it a bug or am I doing something very very wrong?

Sorry for my bad English and thanks in advance!